# Showing and hiding a panel with a button winforms (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void AddPersonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = NameTextBox.Text;
            string surname = SurnameTextBox.Text;
            int age = int.Parse(AgeTextBox.Text);
            Person person = new Person(name, surname, age);
            persons.Add(person);
            RefreshListBox();
            NameTextBox.Text = "";
            SurnameTextBox.Text = "";
            AgeTextBox.Text = "";
        }
        private void DeletePersonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person selectedPerson = PersonsListBox.SelectedItem as Person;
            if (selectedPerson != null)
            {               persons.Remove(selectedPerson);
                RefreshListBox();
            }
        }
        private void RefreshListBox()
        {
           PersonsListBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Person p in persons)
            {               PersonsListBox.Items.Add(p);
            }
        }
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public Person(string name, string surname, int age)
            {
                Name = name;
                Surname = surname;
                Age = age;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Name} {Surname} ({Age})";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna add a button Show, and when pressing it on a person we created earlier, it should open a panel where we can save or edit the info. I can't seem to implement the Show button so the panel doesn't show before we press the Show, but only after

When pressing a button Show it should show the panel

Comment: Please edit your post to remove the blank line you've got between each *useful* line of code. It makes the code much harder to read. I'm sure you wouldn't want to read code laid out like this while working on it, so please don't ask others to do so when helping you.

Comment: Additionally, your namespace is `WinFormsApp1` but you've applied the wpf tag. Which is it?

Comment: This seems to be a plain WinForms question. If this is the case please remove the WPF tag and add the WinForms tag.

Comment: Instead of Panel probably simpler to create a separate Form with fields to edit Person and buttons to save or cancel changes. Pass selected Person from current Form to new Form (through constructor probably). As Person is reference type, you'll see changes in current Form after edits in new Form and its closing.

Comment: See my rwo form project.  Form 2 instead of closing will hide so you can reopen : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net